# How to Group and display count of each type of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Suppose I have a column which has three types of data like A, B, C. I want to group and count the number of each type.
For example if A is 3 times in column , B is 2 times and C is 1 time. 
It should display as:

```
A    B     C
3    2     1
```

I would appreciate your help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data in one row, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(col = 'a') as A, sum(col = 'b') as b, sum(col = 'c') as c
from t;
```

You can try the more explicit:

```
select sum(case when col = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when col = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as b,
       sum(case when col = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) as c
from t;
```

Comment: This works, but the output is shown in the negative?

Comment: @NIKHILLAHOTY . . . This should not produce negative values.

Comment: Yes, but it's doing for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NIKHILLAHOTY . . . I suspect it is how you replaced the output.  MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  I don't see how under normal circumstances adding such values could result in a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest the following query:

```
SELECT
    data, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY data
```

This would generate counts in row form, e.g.

```
A 3
B 2
C 1
```

Most of the time this would meet your needs.  If you instead really need columns you can try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN data = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN data = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN data = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM yourTable
```

This would generate your literal expected output:

```
A    B    C
3    2    1
```